# C# XML getting a duplicated empty node?

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating a xml document using the following C# code:

```
 XmlDocument finalDoc = new XmlDocument();

 //(1) the xml declaration is recommended, but not mandatory
 XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = finalDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
 XmlElement root = finalDoc.DocumentElement;
 finalDoc.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);

 //(2) string.Empty makes cleaner code
 XmlElement element1 = finalDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "root", string.Empty);
 finalDoc.AppendChild(element1);


 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {

        XmlElement element2 = finalDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty,"song", string.Empty);
        element2.SetAttribute("title", "title" + i);
        element1.AppendChild(element2);

        for (int k=0; k<5;k++)
        {

            XmlElement element3 = finalDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "line", string.Empty);

            element3.InnerText = "text " + k;
            element2.AppendChild(element3);
        }

        element1.AppendChild(element2);
  }

  finalDoc.Save("C:\\Users\\adm\\Downloads\\finalDoc.xml");
```

and I am getting the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>

   <song title="title 0" />
   <song title="title 0">

      <line>text 0</line>
      <line>text 1</line>
      <line>text 2</line>
      <line>text 3</line>
      <line>text 4</line>

   </song>

   <song title="title 1" />
   <song title="title 1">

      ...

   </song>

   ...

</root>
```

As you can see, I am having a duplicated empty "song" node for some reason, what am I missing here?

I don't see anything out of order here, could someone please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: You call AppendChild twice for element2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You AppendChild 2 times `element2`. Remove first one

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    XmlElement element2 = finalDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty,"song", string.Empty);
    element2.SetAttribute("title", "title" + i);

    for (int k=0; k<5;k++)
    {
        XmlElement element3 = finalDoc.CreateElement(string.Empty, "line", string.Empty);
        element3.InnerText = "text " + k;
        element2.AppendChild(element3);
    }
    element1.AppendChild(element2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `element1.AppendChild(element2);` occurs twice in your for loop, third and last line in the loop.